# Need to create a table with values filled in before dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Using redshift. I have a table with the following fields:

```
Column:         Type:
department    | varchar             
employee_ID   | varchar           
event         | varchar     
date          | date
```

And a date table which just has one field and lists all dates. 
There are a few departments with employees within each department. The "Event" field has two possible values: JOIN or LEAVE. A join record is the date they joined the company/department and the LEAVE record is the date they left the company/department. It looks like this:

```
department  employee_id event   date
marketing   001         JOIN    6/17/2017
marketing   002         JOIN    6/19/2017
marketing   002         LEAVE   6/20/2017
marketing   001         LEAVE   6/22/2017
```

I want to make a table that has every day listed (again I have a table with all dates as well) and a value 1 for when they are employed and a value of 0 for when they are not for all employees. This would look like this:

```
date        department  employee_id employed
6/17/2017   marketing   001         1
6/18/2017   marketing   001         1
6/19/2017   marketing   001         1
6/19/2017   marketing   002         1
6/20/2017   marketing   001         1
6/20/2017   marketing   002         1
6/21/2017   marketing   001         1
6/22/2017   marketing   001         1
```

Thinking I may need to create a new table that has start date and leave date in the same row? for that I could use a case statement and partition to get the first and last date but not sure where to go from there... maybe a tally table? That query might look like this but still wouldnt get the desired result:

```
select
department,
employee_id,
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY date ASC) = 1 THEN date
ELSE NULL
END AS join_date,
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY date DESC) = 1 THEN date
ELSE NULL
END AS leave_date
from table1
```

Comment: im using redshift

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a `CROSS JOIN` between your date table and table containing the join and leave dates.

Example data only. You would use your existing tables.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE dim_date (dt_val)
AS        SELECT '2017-06-16'::date dt_val
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-17'::date dt_val
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-18'::date dt_val
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-19'::date dt_val
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-20'::date dt_val
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-21'::date dt_val
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-22'::date dt_val
UNION ALL SELECT '2017-06-23'::date dt_val
;
CREATE TEMP TABLE empl_event (department, employee_id, event, event_dt)
AS        SELECT 'marketing' department, 1 employee_id, 'JOIN'  event, '2017-06-17'::date event_dt
UNION ALL SELECT 'marketing' department, 2 employee_id, 'JOIN'  event, '2017-06-19'::date event_dt
UNION ALL SELECT 'marketing' department, 2 employee_id, 'LEAVE' event, '2017-06-20'::date event_dt
UNION ALL SELECT 'marketing' department, 1 employee_id, 'LEAVE' event, '2017-06-22'::date event_dt
;
```

Logic step 1: Convert `JOIN` and `LEAVE` events to dates on 1 row

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE empl_period (department, employee_id, join_dt, leave_dt)
AS
SELECT department
      ,employee_id
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'JOIN'  THEN event_dt ELSE NULL END) join_dt
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'LEAVE' THEN event_dt ELSE NULL END) leave_dt
FROM empl_event
GROUP BY 1,2
;
```

Logic step 2: Use `CROSS JOIN` to create a row for every possible employee-date combo and set `employed` to 1 if the date is between `join_dt` and  `leave_dt`.

```
SELECT emp.department
      ,emp.employee_id
      ,ddt.dt_val
      ,CASE WHEN ddt.dt_val BETWEEN emp.join_dt AND emp.leave_dt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END employed
FROM       empl_period emp
CROSS JOIN dim_date    ddt
ORDER BY 1,2,3
;
```

Output for example data

```
 department | employee_id |   dt_val   | employed
------------+-------------+------------+----------
 marketing  |           1 | 2017-06-16 |        0
 marketing  |           1 | 2017-06-17 |        1
 marketing  |           1 | 2017-06-18 |        1
 marketing  |           1 | 2017-06-19 |        1
 marketing  |           1 | 2017-06-20 |        1
 marketing  |           1 | 2017-06-21 |        1
 marketing  |           1 | 2017-06-22 |        1
 marketing  |           1 | 2017-06-23 |        0
 marketing  |           2 | 2017-06-16 |        0
 marketing  |           2 | 2017-06-17 |        0
 marketing  |           2 | 2017-06-18 |        0
 marketing  |           2 | 2017-06-19 |        1
 marketing  |           2 | 2017-06-20 |        1
 marketing  |           2 | 2017-06-21 |        0
 marketing  |           2 | 2017-06-22 |        0
 marketing  |           2 | 2017-06-23 |        0
```

Comment: the real file is way too big to manually enter every date for that union.. are there other things I can do?

Comment: `dim_date` and `empl_event` only create sample data for demonstration. There's no need to write any unions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following SQL to expand the dates using to and from dates

```
DECLARE @dateranges TABLE (employee_id VARCHAR(4),
                           department  VARCHAR(20),
                           join_date   DATE,
                           leave_date  DATE)

INSERT @dateranges SELECT employee_id,
                          department,
                          MIN(event_date) join_date,
                          MAX(event_date) leave_date
                     FROM employment
                    GROUP BY employee_id,
                             department;

WITH cte (dt, dept, id, emd) AS
(
   SELECT tbl.join_date AS dt,
          tbl.department AS dept,
          tbl.employee_id AS employee_id,
          1 AS emd
     FROM @dateranges tbl
    UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.dt) AS dt,
          tbl.department AS dept,
          tbl.employee_id AS employee_id,
          1 AS emp
     FROM cte
    INNER JOIN @dateranges tbl
       ON cte.id = tbl.employee_id
      AND cte.dept = tbl.department
    WHERE cte.dt < tbl.leave_date
)

SELECT dt AS date,
       dept AS department,
       id AS employee_id,
       emd AS employed
  FROM cte
 ORDER BY dt, id
```

Result:

```
date    department  employee_id employed
2017-06-17  marketing   001 1
2017-06-18  marketing   001 1
2017-06-19  marketing   001 1
2017-06-19  marketing   002 1
2017-06-20  marketing   001 1
2017-06-20  marketing   002 1
2017-06-21  marketing   001 1
2017-06-22  marketing   001 1
```

Comment: This looks great thank you! One question, I was told a cross join function would do this but that doesn't appear to be available in redshift. Do you have any idea if cross join is an operator in redshift or if there are alternatives?

Comment: This SQL is not applicable to Redshift.